# rotate image urls in img tag to preload all

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm currently writing an HTML5 P&C aventure.

Since there are many images and sprites to load before the game can start I wanted to preload all images.

My idea was to create a single `<img>` and make it `visibility: hidden;`, so the user does not see anything.

After every loaded image I want to execute a function that updates a progressbar.

So I did something like this:

```
loadImages: function () {                                                       
    $('#preLoader').attr('src', this.__images[0]).on('load', this.loadCallback);
},                                                                              

loadCallback: function () {                                                     
    this.__images.splice(0, 1);                                                 

    Game.events.trigger('progressbar:bar:step');                                

    if(this.__images.length > 0) {                                              
        this.loadImages();                                                      
    }                                                                           
    else if(!this.__fired) {                                                    
        this.__fired = true;    

        this.trigger('finished');                                             
    }                                                                           
}.$bound(),
```

`this.__images` is an array containing all urls to be loaded, the callback function basically calls the progressbar to update and checks if there are images left and then again calls the first function.

Thing is, that it seems, that the `load` event does not really wait until the image is loaded, because under a 1ms after the `src` attribut of the `<img>` has been changed the callback gets fired.

So this might not work properly

Is there a way to achieve this like I want to?

Basically I want the image to be loaded complete and then fire the callback, then again load the image, etc... until all images in the array are loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this jquery plugin: http://alz.so/imageloader/

It has all the functionality I need and even more.